# Testing saving nested arrays using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to be able to use [hurl.it](https://www.hurl.it/) (or similar service) to test saving some data to my Mongoose DB. I can't figure out how to structure the parameters so that I can save nested arrays.

Here's my schema:

```
var Events = new Schema({
    title: String,
    subtitle: String,
    start: Date,
    end: Date,
    description: String,
    handle: String,
    published: Boolean,
    location: {
        lat: String, 
        lng: String
    },
    costs: [{
        price: Number,
        description: String,
        cost_type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Pre-Sale', 'Door', 'Online', 'Box Office', 'Suggested Donation', 'Discount', 'Children', 'Senior']
        },
        created: {type: Date}
    }],
    created: {type: Date}
});
```

I've tried sending `costs.price` and `costs.0.price` as request params, and also tried sending a JSON object as a string in the request body. It will save the document with all of the simple variables, title, subtitle, etc., but it just ignores the costs information.

**EDIT:**

Thought I should mention that passing in `costs.0.price` as a param crashes node. Here's the dump:

```
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:94
     doc.validate(function (err) {
         ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'validate'
     at 
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:94:13
     at 
/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:102:9
     at DocumentArray.SchemaType.doValidate (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:603:22)
     at DocumentArray.doValidate (/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/documentarray.js:73:35)
     at /node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:970:9
     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
24 Mar 10:11:07 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```